# Unable to run mongodb-community edition

Tags: mongodb

I have install mongodb community edition using brew but I am unable to run it. When I run

`brew services restart mongoldb-community`

I get the message:

```
Warning: mongodb-community must be run as non-root to start at user login!
==> Successfully started `mongodb-community` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community)
```

But when I run brew services list I get the following:

```
Name              Status  User Plist
mongodb-community error   root /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist
```

What is going on?